# How to get the most expensive item in a category using 2 tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get to show only the category that have the most expensive item.

I tried and with the query I have I get all categories and the price of the most expensive item in every category, but I don't know how to do to just get just the one category that have the most expensive.

```
select categories.category ,max(purchase_price) as dyrast_bok
from categories
inner join books on categories.category_id = books.category_id
group by categories.category;
```

The tables:

```
CATEGORIES ( category_id (PK), category )

BOOKS ( book_id (PK), title, publisher_id (FK), published_year,
 purchase_price, category_id (FK),purchase_date, pages,
 book_type_id (FK) )
```

Comment: why not `select category from (YOUR QUERY) as q` ?..

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie, i.e. two different books with the same highest price?

Answer (score 1):

```
select categories.category ,purchase_price as dyrast_bok
from categories
inner join books on categories.category_id = books.category_id
where purchase_price in (select max(purchase_price) from books)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to order by `max(purchase_price) desc` and take the first one:

```
select *
from (your query with order by max(purchase_price) desc)
limit 1
```

Comment: i know, but if i do that all categories will still show, i know wich category have the most expensive item but i only want that category to show

Comment: With LIMIT 1 you'll only get one row returned.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to do it with subquery: you need to get the most expensive for category, order it by max(purchase_price) and then take the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use aliases so you can reuse them in the `GROUP BY` part, and use [`top 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453592/sql-select-top-1) to get only the highest result when you order by `max(b.purchase_price)`.

This is how should be your query:

```
select top 1 c.category , max(b.purchase_price) as dyrast_bok
from categories c
inner join books b on categories.category_id = books.category_id
order by dyrast_bok 
group by c.category;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the problem. OP want one single row returned, not one per category.

Comment: I don't think Postgresql supports MS SQL Server's `TOP 1` construction. Besides an ORDER BY is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: Have a sub-query that returns the max purchase_price.

```
select c.category, b.purchase_price as dyrast_bok
from categories c
inner join books b on c.category_id = b.category_id
where b.purchase_price = (select max(purchase_price) from books)
```

Will return both books in case of a tie!

Alternative solution:

```
select c.category, b.purchase_price as dyrast_bok
from categories c
inner join books b on c.category_id = b.category_id
order by b.purchase_price desc
fetch first 1 row
```

Will not include ties, only one row will be returned. (AFAIK Postgresql doesn't support FETCH FIRST WITH TIES.)